# Apache Sling Resource Mapping in CQ 5.6.1

Tags: aem, sling

I've been taking several hours fiddling this [Resource Mapping](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/deploying/resource_mapping.html) for no luck. I have put a new node in `/etc/map/http` named `GoogleAnalyticsMap`. It had the following properties:

```
Name: jcr:primaryType
Type: Name
Value: sling:Mapping

Name: sling:internalRedirect
Type: String
Value: /content/dam/website/Common/my_google_analytics_key.html

Name: sling:match
Type: String
Value: [^/]+/[^/]+/my_google_analytics_key.html
```

Funnily, when i checked to [`/system/console/jcrresolver` or Adobe CQ Web Console Sling Resource Resolver](http://localhost:4502/system/console/jcrresolver). It resolves into the following

```
Pattern: ^http/[^/]+/[^/]+/my_google_analytics_key.html
Replacement: /content/dam/website/Common/my_google_analytics_key.html
Redirect: internal
```

I have no idea how they could register `^[^/]+/[^/]+/welcome$` as shown in the example and did not have the 'http' there. Nevertheless, whenever i try to hit the pattern locally (i.e. http://localhost:4502/my_google_analytics_key.html) it only shows resource not found. Also checked through the Configuration test section that available in **Adobe CQ Web Console Sling Resource Resolver** it says that it can't resolve. Did i miss something?

```
    , type=sling:nonexisting, path=/my_google_analytics_key.html, resource=[NonExistingResource, path=/my_google_analytics_key.html]
```

Thank you for the help.

p.s. i've checked the [Sling documentation](http://sling.apache.org/documentation/the-sling-engine/mappings-for-resource-resolution.html) also, however, it baffles me that i can't add `sling:alias`, perhaps its also something to do with the sling version. Nevertheless, i should ask this as second question later, once the `sling:match` is working properly.

**Edit**: fiddling a bit, changing the `sling:match` to `localhost.4502/google.html` does let it to redirect `localhost:4502/google.html` to the desired DAM item. Well, i'm still asking for 'domain-free' matching though.. so i have no trouble when using the mapping for all environment i have..

**Edit**, Updates:

- Apparently due to me put the new `sling:Mapping` under `http` folder it will always prefix the path with http. Perhaps the example is meant to be put **not** under `http` folder.
- Next item is, it will always assume the matching item will be protocols, domain, and port separated by dots (yes, even `\.` is not a valid input and CQ or rather sling will sanitize it somehow). Something like `*.(4502|4503|80|443)/my_google_analytics_key.html` will accept any domains and those designated ports. I do wonder if it really the case, since they says regex but it does not feel so much regex.
- Some says that `sling:internalRedirect` should be a `String[]` - yes i know the docs says `String`. I have not test this further and take it as it is..

Comment: you can just put `^http/[^/]+/[^/]+/my_google_analytics_key.html` in `sling:match`

Comment: hmm, intriguing, its mapped to `^http/^http/[^/]+/[^/]+/google.html` in the Sling Resource Resolver.